# How to display array elements like a matrix using ngFor and table [Angular]

Tags: html, css, ngfor

I'm creating a Month picker in Angular. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656742/how-to-use-ngfor-to-display-the-data-as-matrix), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502266/how-do-i-create-a-3x3-grid-via-css/46260247) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821300/ionic-2-display-array-of-items-in-a-3x3-table) also but cannot achieve what I want. I've months from Jan to Dec. I want to display them like a 4X3 matrix. But I'm getting all the months in a single column vertically. Or may be that I'm unnecessarily over complicating my code. Here is my code.

**monthpikcer.component.html**

```
<div class="my-table-div">
  <table class="my-table" *ngFor="let row of months">
    <tr class="month-row" *ngFor="let col of row">
      <td class="month-name">{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

**monthpicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MonthpickerComponent implements OnInit {

  months = [
    ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
    ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep'],
    ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

PS: I don't want to use bootstrap `row` and `col`. My code is not working. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use this

<table class="my-table">
    <tr class="month-row" *ngFor="let row of months; index as i">       
            <table class="my-table">
                <tr class="month-row"  >
                    <td *ngFor="let col of row" class="month-name">{{col}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Output is**

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Jan</td><td>Feb</td><td>Mar</td></tr>
<tr><td>Apr</td><td>may</td><td>Jun</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jul</td><td>Aug</td><td>Sep</td></tr>
<tr><td>Oct</td><td>Nov</td><td>Dec</td></tr>
<table>
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use css styles for it like below.

```
.my-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.month-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

checkout this demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59081856.